# Joining an integer input to an element in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have one fuction that has a list of commands ,eg,

```
def commands(user_input):
    command_list = ["OFF","HELP","FORWARD "]
    if user_input in command_list:
        return True
    return False
```

How ever i need to do another function that controls how many steps forward the forward command goes.

```
def forward_command(robot_name,user_command):
    steps = int()
    print(f'{robot_name} moved {user_command} by {steps} steps.')
```

This is what i did so far, however I am not getting the correct output.
This is what the out suppose to look like:

What do you want to name your robot? HAL
HAL: Hello kiddo!
HAL: What must I do next? forward 10

> HAL moved forward by 10 steps.
> HAL: What must I do next?

THIS IS WHAT MINES LOOKS LIKE :
What do you want to name your robot? HAL
HAL: Hello kiddo!
HAL: What must I do next? forward
10

> HAL moved forward by 10 steps.
> HAL: What must I do next?

My 10 goes onto the next line.

Comment: What exactly is the significance of your `commands()` function? And can you expand your question to include the code you're using to get user input?

Comment: The user will select a command from my list, each element in the list links up to a function, however my LMS expects me to reflect the command Forward followed by the number of steps in one go "Forward 10", the number of steps change all the time. I cant get it to merge two inputs and keep it on the same line.